# Cakephp vs Joomla Components and Modules

Tags: cakephp, joomla, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

This question is about Cakephp, I am really confused on cakephp I just noticed that if i'm not mistaken cakephp does not have components and modules like Joomla does?

am I right that cakephp doesn't have components and modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your a little bit confused about the two concepts. You can't compare cakephp and joomla cause joomla is a CMS (Content Manger System) while Cakephp is a PHP Framework. Thus Cakephp has her own logic and joomla components and modules are addressed in some other way (blocks, elements, plugins, behaviors ect ...)

Comment: oh ok thanks so cakephp has it's own thing (blocks, elements, plugins, behaviors) am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what can be compared with the CakePHP framework is the Joomla framework 
http://framework.joomla.org with whom you can write your web apps. But the Joomla framework does also not come with component, module and plugin support as this is CMS specific.

It was recently released in version 1.0 http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5521-joomla-framework-1-0-released.html.